# R: Iteratively extract not NA values for columns in a data table and split into separate columns without typing column names

Tags: r, iteration, data.table, dplyr, multiple-columns

I am working with a large dataset containing many variables. Therefore, I want to avoid typing in column names at all times. I want to iterate through the columns in my data and extract the value contained fields per column. In other words, I want to end up with separate data tables for each column, none of them containing NA values.

My approach is to write a loop that first eliminates the NA values per column. I extracted the column names in a separate column matrix when reading the .csv file (using fread). The problem is that I did not manage to exclude the column names or the NA with my approach. I worked out a small example to illustrate the problem:

```
# Example data 
dt = data.table(color=c("b","g","r","y",NA), 
                 size=c("S", "XL", NA, NA, "M"), 
                 number=(1:5))
columns = matrix(c("color", "size", "number"), nrow=3, ncol=1)
```

The loop shown below works, although it is not really a loop because it still requires inserting the column name in the first line:

```
# Works (but requires typing in the column name)
for(i in 1:1){
  var <- dt %>% group_by(color) %>% filter(!is.na(color))
  name <- paste("new", columns[i], sep=".")
  assign(name, var[, columns[i], with=FALSE])}

# Output:
  color
(chr)
 1     b
 2     g
 3     r
 4     y
```

My idea is to refer inside the loop to the subsequent columns by using the extracted column names. The problem here is that the NA values do not get eliminated, i.e., the first line of code inside the loop is not working:

```
# Does not work
for(i in 1:1){
  var <- dt %>% group_by(columns[i]) %>% filter(!is.na(columns[i]))
  name <- paste("new", columns[i], sep=".")
  assign(name, var[, columns[i], with=FALSE])}

# Output:
  color
(chr)
1     b
2     g
3     r
4     y
5    NA
```

Can anyone help me out to end up with separate columns (of unequal lengths) that do not contain NA values, without typing in the column names? (Another approach than I have used is certainly welcome as well.) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

```
sapply(columns, function(x) c(na.omit(dt[[x]])), USE.NAMES = T)
#$color
#[1] "b" "g" "r" "y"
#
#$size
#[1] "S"  "XL" "M" 
#
#$number
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

The `c()` isn't necessary - I just used it to strip `na.omit` class info to make the output clearer.

And don't use `assign` - just store the items in a list as above and work with that.

Comment: Thanks @eddi, this works quite well. I end up with a list containing each column which I can extract separately if I wish to. 

The reason that I used assign is because I want to be the name giving of the columns to be automated as well. Using your answer, I would still need a loop with assign to automate the process of extracting each column from the list and simultaneously give them names. 

So your answer helps me out for half the question, but perhaps the issue of automatically naming data (tables) by using numbers/indexes instead of typing in names is a separate question!

Comment: @SophieClock I'm a little confused what you mean - the list above does have named elements

Comment: Hi @eddi, I'll try to explain. I do have named columns, but I prefer not to use them. This because my real dataset contains hundreds of variables and typing all these names all the time is not an efficient way to do analysis. That's why I try to automate the process by first using a loop that perceives the columns by number and then later on put a label on these columns (which I automatically stored in an array when reading in the data).

Comment: Update: I found the answer to my question using the 'get' option:  
`for(i in 1:3){  
  var <- dt %>% group_by(get(columns[i])) %>% filter(!is.na(get(columns[i])))  
  name <- paste("new", columns[i], sep=".")  
  assign(name, var[,columns[i], with=FALSE])}`